Stopping keyboard event propagation with IOKit
I am writing a program for MacOs to generate midi commands from key strokes on a computer keyboard. After identifying the device and sending the midi command to a client, I would like to prevent the key stroke from reaching the foreground application. Can I do that?
So, the program should:

Intercept key strokes
Understand which keyboard they come from

If they come from a certain keyboard, send a midi command to a MIDIClient and prevent propagation of the keystroke to the foreground application
Otherwise, ignore the keystroke and let it propagate



I have implemented everything that I need, the only missing thing is preventing the event from propagating. I believe that I would also need a way to ensure that the program gets to consume the event before any foreground application.
I used this github project as a starting point as it does keyboard detection. It is implemented in Swift and it uses IOKit.hid for the functionality, and the logic is mostly implemented inside an IOHIDValueCallback.
As I am completely new to MacOs development, I am not even sure that this is the right path/toolkit. Surprisingly, I found very little documentation on this subject.
For the record, I would be much happier to implement the same functionality in Python, but I understood (but I may be wrong) that differentiating between input sources is not possible with a Python API.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I don't understand why the question received 2 "close" votes. The complaint seems to be that there is no specific problem or error. But I am not asking how to fix an error, I am asking how to implement a certain functionality within a certain framework. I don't have an MWE because I don't know how it should look like, that's why I am asking for help.

How do you catch the keystrokes? Post a [mre] please.

Did you see Keystrokes are not blocked when using kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice and are still passed to the OS?

Thanks for the pointer, @Willeke. kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice is something to try out.
